# PHP round adds decimals if a precision is defined

Tags: php, rounding

I've looked everywhere but I can't seem to figure this out. I have a bunch off coordinates which have up to 6 decimal places and I want to round everything down to only 2 decimals.

So for example a number can be '82.599899' and it should become '82.60'. The problem is that if I use round($number, 2) it turns into this:

82.599999999999994316

So a bunch of examples are:

```
round(82.599899);  //returns 83
round(82.599899, 2); //returns 82.599999999999994316
floor(82.599899* 100) / 100; //returns 82.599999999999994316
round(28.4772, 2); //returns 28.480000000000000426
```

Am I simply doing something wrong? I've never had issues with round, floor etz before so I'm pretty clueless right now

Comment: For me it's working as expected. Did you maybe changed something in the php.ini?

Comment: No, you're doing it right. Does the number get stored in a variable that later gets modified by a different line or are you outputting it directly? Have you tried inspecting the output of round() in a debugger?

Comment: @KhorneHoly Ugh yes I found it, someone in my group must have changed it. The precision value in the php.ini was set to 20 instead off the default 14 for some reason

Comment: @Crecket did that solved your problem?

Comment: @KhorneHoly yes it did, submit it as a answer and ill mark it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this is working as expected.

```
round(82.599899);  //returns 83
round(82.599899, 2); //returns 82.60
round(28.4772, 2); //returns 28.48
```

So I guess that this is a config problem. Did you changed something in your `php.ini`? Maybe the `precision` field is changed from the default one.

Comment: Yes, in php.ini there is a line precision=? and it was set to 20 instead off the default which is 14